# Adding User Profile object as you add new User

Tags: django-admin

Hi I am trying to add the user profile object as i add a new user but i always get "'User' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used."  error.

Here are my user profile class and admin class:

```
class User_Profile(models.Model):
    user                = models.OneToOneField(User)
    country             = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    phone_number        = models.CharField(max_length=16)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_profile'
        unique_together = ('user', 'country')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = User_Profile

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = AddUserForm
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username',)}),
        (('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}),
        (('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
        (('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser')}),
        (('Groups'), {'fields': ('groups',)}),
    )
    inlines = [UserProfileInline]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        new_user = request.user
        new_user.save()
        user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
        user_profile.user = new_user
        user_profile.country = request.POST['country']
        user_profile.country = request.POST['phone_number']
        user_profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,primary_key = True)
```

maybe u should do like this.

Comment: wow. that did the trick. thanks

although i needed to change the save_model a bit
    `def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        new_user = obj
        new_user.save()
        try:
            user_profile = new_user.get_profile()
            user_profile.save()
        except User_Profile.DoesNotExist:
            user_profile =  User_Profile (user = new_user,country = Country.objects.get(pk = request.POST['user_profile-0-country']),phone_number = request.POST['user_profile-0-phone_number'])
            user_profile.save(force_insert=True)`